# Did Charles Xavier train Magneto in the comics?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto, x-men-first-class

In the movie *X-Men: First Class*, if memory serves, Charles works with a group of mutants training them to control and increase their abilities.

Although the initiative is presented as coming from both him and Erik, Magneto also receives training. There’s one scene where he repeatedly tries to move a satellite antenna until he finally does. To an extent this to me paints Charles as a mentor to Magneto which is not the vibe I get from the comics where they are more like equals.

I don’t recall this happening in the comics but my experience is from many years ago and only with the new X-Men series.

Without the specifics does Magneto receive training from Xavier in the comics?

Comment: *Which* comics? The x-men continuity spans decades and multiple retcons, reboots and resurrections

Comment: Didn’t know there were several versions. I’ve read long a go the uncanny X-men 95 onwards to about 260 or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

In *The Uncanny X-Men* #161, Magnus [the name he gave at the time] and Charles met in Israel, for the first time, where Charles had been called in to help a Holocaust victim who was a patient in the hospital, and Magnus already worked in the hospital, showing great skill, like many Holocaust survivors, with the victims.  Charles guesses that Magnus may be a mutant because he resists his telepathy.

They become friends and intensely discuss the possibility of mutants, with Magnus taking the position they would be in danger, but entirely theoretical.

Not until Hydra attacks and kidnaps a friend of theirs do they clearly reveal their powers to each other.  Magnus  angrily says that Charles must have guessed, but with the end of the fight, he concludes that Charles and he have philosophical differences that can't be bridged, and leaves with the gold that Hydra was after.

Furthermore during the fight, Magnus was already quite competent with his skills.  He explodes Hydra aircraft in midair and carries off the gold with his powers.  He doesn't need training.

(I also note that he worked in the extermination camp in Auschwitz in the comics; no one discovered his powers and experimented on him for them, so while he was deeply traumatized, he was not in particular traumatized about his powers.)